# MySQL change engine big millions rows table

Tags: mysql, innodb

I want to change engine of 2 million rows table from MyISAM to InnoDB. I am afraid of this long time operation, so I created similar structure InnoDB table and now I want to copy all data from old one to this new one. What is the fastest way? SELECT INSERT? What about START TRANSACTION? Please, help. I dont want to hang my server.

Comment: Schedule a downtime.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor: copy the whole setup to your local machine and try it all out there. You'll have a much better idea of what you are getting into. Just be aware of potential differences in hardware between your production server and your local machine.

The fastest way is probably the most straightforward way:

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you cannot do it any faster than what is built into the ALTER. And it does have to copy over all the data and rebuild all the indexes.

Be sure to have `innodb_buffer_pool_size` raised to prepare for InnoDB.  And lower `key_buffer_size` to allow room.  Suggest 35% and 12% of RAM, respectively, for the transition.  After all tables are converted, suggest 70% and a mere 20MB.

One slight speedup is to do some select that fetches the entire table and the entire `PRIMARY KEY` (if it can be cached).  This will do some I/O before really starting.  Example:  `SELECT avg(id) FROM tbl` where id is the primary key.  And `SELECT avg(foo) FROM tbl` where foo is not indexed but it numeric.  These will force a full scan of the PK index and the data, thereby caching the stuff that the `ALTER` will have to read.

Other tips on converting: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb .